# Trying to debug an application that starts up via an "exec" gradle task

Tags: debugging, gradle, wildfly

I have a gradle task (type - exec). In this task I start a WildFly server using a standart bat file (standalone.bat). The war file is already in deployments beforehand, so the server starts up and everything works fine.

The problem appears when I need to debug the actual application on the server. Running the gradle task in a debug mode doesn't help, as it can only debug the actual gradle task itself and not the application that it starts.

I know, there is a solution to this problem using an additional configuration that would allow me to debug a remote java application. However, the goal for me right now is to move eveything onto gradle tasks and not have any configurations set up in my IDE.

I need to be able to run a gradle exec task that would start up my server and than to debug whatever application it deploys. Is there a way to do this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: I've never used Wildfly

Ultimately you'll want to edit `standalone.bat` so that you include an additional arguments to the `java.exe` invocation. Take a look inside `standalone.bat` many applications include a line commented out that you can uncomment to enable debugging.

Eg sample argument to add to the `java.exe` call

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=1044
```

You may wish to take a copy of `standalone.bat` which you call `standalone-debug.bat` which you invoke via gradle

Comment: So basically, I would need to add this as an argument inside my gradle task?

Comment: No, you would need to edit `standalone.bat` to add the argument

Comment: I have something like this in my standalone.bat:                                                 if  '"%DEBUG_MODE%" == "true" (
   echo "%JAVA_OPTS%" | findstr /I "\-agentlib:jdwp" > nul
  if errorlevel == 1 (
     set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=%DEBUG_PORT%,server=y,suspend=n"
  ) else (
     echo Debug already enabled in JAVA_OPTS, ignoring --debug argument
)  )'
From what I understand, I just need to run bat file like this: standalone.bat --debug <port>. But if I try to use the same port as my application is using (8080) server doesn't start up

Comment: You'll need to choose another port. Debugging needs it's own port. You'll have to pick a port number that's not in use

Comment: This way I can only debug it if I also create a new remote Run Configuration and run it. Is there a way to do it without another run configuration but straight from a gradle task?

Comment: It seems you want to run Wildfly "embedded" within the Gradle jvm rather than starting a separate jvm via `standalone.bat`. Or perhaps you're OK with running locally using jetty or Tomcat instead of Wildfly? In which case you could use [gretty](https://gretty-gradle-plugin.github.io/gretty-doc/). Otherwise I suggest you Google "Wildfly embedded". Another thing you could do is add an "echo" to `standalone.bat` to see which main class it's running (and the args). You could then run the same embedded in the Gradle jvm

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will look into this!

Comment: Please note that eclipse calls gradle via the [tooling API](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/embedding.html) which uses the Gradle Daemon. So eclipse and the Daemon will still be separate JVM's (so you'll still need a remote debug target in eclipse). So instead of a gradle task you will need to fire Wildfly directly in eclipse (using a run target) if you want eclipse to "own" the Wildfly JVM. I think you'll just end up using a remote debug target and `standalone.bat` and give up on the embedded idea

Comment: Seems like remote is the only reasonobale option. Shame, since I was trying to move the entire project onto gradle and not use anything specific to an IDE. Anyway, thank you very much for your time